# Youtube Search Results as Playlist, Need Advise

Tags: youtube, wordpress, youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api

> Hi guys, this is my first time to post on this awesome community so
>   please bear with me.

I am working with a Wordpress Plugin that can display a *Youtube Search Results* into *Video Playlist.*

**My settings are:**

- Keywords
- Author
- Content- channel/keyword

---

**My first Approach was this:**

[with this api as reference](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_api_query_parameters#formatsp),

search for the keyword > display the relevant results according to the author as playlist

*I'm in doubt if I this is possible, coding 30%

*I'm not sure where could I use my settings for *Content*

---

but then when my coding is in progress I recently bumped an [article](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_playlists#Retrieving_playlists) that says Youtube Search is differrent on Searching a Youtube Playlist

---

> Now I can't continue my coding because I'm not sure If I'm doing it
>   right. Can you give me some advise with this situation or show me some
>   similar project/examples?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to write any YouTube Data API code for this; it's a built-in feature of the YouTube Player.

[This blog post](http://apiblog.youtube.com/2012/03/new-player-options-for-lists-of-videos.html) has an example of loading a list player that takes its content from the recent uploads of a channel. You can do something similar by setting `listType=search&list=SEARCH_TERM`, where `SEARCH_TERM` is whatever string you want to search for (be sure to URL escape it). You can read more in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#loadPlaylistObj).